# Alternate lambda functions deployment for production

Tags: serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I'm developping a web extension for the chrome store that calls a backend deployed on aws lambda using the serverless framework.

When developing the Rest API, I may introduce breaking chances. As publishing an update on the chrome store can take a lot of time and is unpredictable (1 day to 3 weeks), the solution I'm think about to keep a compatible API with the extension is to deploy 2 different lambda functions in production.

The idea is when I push new changes on the master branch, the lambda function with the oldest version is updated and ready to receive calls as soon as the update is approved on the chrome store, without erasing the API currently used.

- First, is it a good pattern to handle the updates of a client consuming an API when you don't have full control on them?
- Second, is this something doable with the serverless framework and how? I couln't find any resources on the subject.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think 2 Lambdas is the solution. Lambdas support versioning and aliasing, which should solve your problem. I assume you have API Gateway in between "users" and the Lambdas. Your web extension calls API Gateway with a GET request to a /foo endpoint, then you configure the /foo endpoint in API Gateway to talk to a specific version/alias of your Lambda. The AWS standard is an alias of "live" on whatever version of your lambda should be in production.

Comment: That sounds like a good solution. I'll dig into that :+1: